# Setting up firebase skeleton rules

Tags: firebase

I have an app that a client uses as a template by copying all the app's html, creating a new firebase for the new instance, and setting the firebase url in the json config. I'm looking for a way to install a predefined set of access rules without the client having to get in the way. Is this possible via the javascript API, or other method? Maybe when the first user is logged in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

> curl https://samplechat.firebaseio-demo.com/.settings/rules.json?auth=FIREBASE_SECRET
>
> curl -X PUT -d '{ "rules": { ".read": true } }' https://samplechat.firebaseio-demo.com/.settings/rules.json?auth=FIREBASE_SECRET

See: https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-security-rules